# What is a reasonable length limit on Type.FullName fields?

Tags: .net, sql, namespaces

I'm going to store Type.FullName, i.e. 'System.String' in a database field. Type names that will be stored are arbitrary, not under my control. What is the max length for a type name?

**EDIT:** I will not be using this info to create instances of the type, it is just used for filtering/sorting/grouping, so storing just FullName instead of AssemblyQualifiedName is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no maximum length I'm aware of... so you should probably go for a maximum *sensible* length. Something like 256 should be adequate for anything sensible, IMO. 128 may well be fine, but if you have a deep namespace hierarchy and a long outer class name and a long nested class name, I guess it's *possible* that a real type name would go over 128...

Are you definitely okay with just the type name without assembly information? If you need to be able to get the type using `Type.GetType(string)` you will need assembly information unless it's in the currently executing assembly or mscorlib. Obviously that adds a considerable length to the string involved...

EDIT: As noted in your comment, if you use a *constructed* generic type, the names could get long very quickly. So whereas `typeof(List<>).FullName` is quite short, `typeof(List<string>).FullName` is not.

If you're going to be storing constructed generic types, it's probably worth giving a pretty large limit. Still, I'd hope that something like 4096 should be enough in most cases :)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, this is not relevant but it is interesting to know that any generic type parameters will be represented as AssemblyQualifiedName which could increase the length drastically. See second remark here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx

Comment: I won't be using this field for getting the actual type, it is just used for filtering/grouping/sorting.